# Combine Inno Setup preprocessor #define from other #defines

Tags: macros, installation, inno-setup

I have an Inno Setup script.

In this Inno Setup script is a `#define` called `InstallParameters`.  This is where the command line arguments for a program will go.  The command line arguments will be any of four flags, `/v`, `/i`, `/a`, `/c` followed by arguments.  For example, here would be an average input into `InstallParameters`:

```
#define InstallParameters "/v Local Area Connection /i 111.11.11.11"
```

Or:

```
#define InstallParameters "/a Device Name /c Customer Name"
```

Or:

```
#define InstallParameters "/v Local Area Connection /i 111.11.11.11 /a Device Name /c Customer Name"
```

Or any combination of a flag followed by an argument.

What I would like to do is make the four arguments into variables themselves, an amalgamation of `#define`.

Here is my ideal (please note that the syntax used to combine the `#define`is entirely fictitious):

```
#define Connection "/v Local Area Connection"
#define IPaddress "/i 1.1.1.1"
#define DeviceName "/a Device Name"
#define CustName "/c Customer"

#define InstallParameters "{#Connection} {#IPaddress} {#DeviceName} {#CustName}"
```

Alas, none of the blind attempts I've tried have worked (some of them compile, though, which is nice).

Honestly, I don't know if this is a *Pascal* thing or an *Inno Setup script* thing.  My attempts at the googles haven't resulted in anything worthwhile, because I don't know enough about either language/script to ask a worthwhile query.

Does anyone know if this sort of thing -- an amalgamation of `#define` -- is possible?  And, if yes, how to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`#define` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=define) can be followed by a C-like expression.

In the expression, you can use `+` operator to concatenate strings *(what you cannot actually use in C)*:

```
#define InstallParameters Connection + " " + IPaddress + " " + DeviceName + " " + CustName
```

---

See also [Inno Setup Preprocessor: Expression Syntax](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=expressions). Though it is helpful only partially.

Comment: OUCH!  Occam's Razor cuts DEEP.  I tried everything that I could possibly think of except the most obvious answer, which, of course, works.  Simply "+" them together!